# jQuery: Function not being called after event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to invoke a callback based on a triggered "click" event. This approach is a hack to log out, which is only available after a click on a button.

When I do the trigger command in the console, the `keyup` event handler works as expected after the trigger.

Trying to automate this process with code using the following does not work however:

```
let editorSwitchTmce = jQuery( ".wp-editor-tabs .switch-tmce" ),
    editorCallback = function() {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.on( "keyup", function () {
        console.log( tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() );
    });
};

editorSwitchTmce.bind("click", function () {
    editorCallback();
});

editorSwitchTmce.trigger( "click" );
```

The problem is, that the `activeEditor` is null until this click. So why is this not working? I mean I'm triggering the click and expecting that the `activeEditor` is set like when I do it with manually in the console of the browser?

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you needing to delay the call to `editorCallback()` when a "real click" happens? ie, to ensure that other code has time to assign the `activeEditor`?

Comment: The call needs to get done right after the click on the button. So when it is done u know?

Comment: ok - have you tried this? `editorSwitchTmce.bind( "mouseup", .. )`

Comment: The event is not the problem i think. When I do first the trigger and add then the on keyup, everything works.

Comment: Another option might be to use a brief timeout: `editorSwitchTmce.bind( "click", function () {
setTimeout(function() { editorCallback(); }, 100);
} );`

Comment: So you think it's a problem with the priority?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197464/discussion-between-dacre-denny-and-mr-jo).

Comment: @DacreDenny It's working. You can post it as answer so I can give you a check - if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a two ways this might be resolved - these depend on other constraints in your code. The preferable approach would be to call `editorCallback()` on `mouseup`:

```
editorSwitchTmce.bind( "mouseup", function () {
    editorCallback();
});
```

This assumes that other code somewhere else in your app has initialised `tinyMCE.activeEditor` prior to the mouseup event of that click phase.

Failing this, you could opt for `editorCallback()` being called after a brief timeout - the idea being that `tinyMCE.activeEditor` is initialised after the timeout duration lapses:

```
editorSwitchTmce.bind( "click", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        editorCallback();
    }, 100);
});
```

The timeout method is really a last-ditch "escape hatch" to solve this issue (ie if you're unable to correct the overall design of the app, etc). It can cause subtle system or momentary visual side effects, so use with caution.

Hope that helps!